# Prefetching data in mobie client

Tags: caching, mobile, prefetch

I'm trying to gain some insight into best practices about "fetching more data than immediately required in order to use them soon after and thus delivering better user experience". I am out of key-words to begin my search. Suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the correct term to look after is "Prefetching" !